# How to automatically sorting continuously only if a certain value is set for a certain column in Google Apps Script/Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**[How My Current Google Sheet works]**
I have a table that has the following headers in the exact order and it has all sorts of data.

Date, Ticket ID, Ticket Link, Ticket Type, Category, Subcategory, Status, Customer

[What the sheet looks like (Certain information has been removed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjNRW.jpg)

**[Goal]**
I want to be able to bring all the rows to the top that has a status with anything except for "Finished." And at the same time sort the entire table with the "Date" column. So I want this to be continuous and want the rows with the "Finished" "Status" to all be under the rows with the rest of the statuses.

**[What's the issue]**
I've constructed the following script, to sort the data, however there are two main issues.

1. I don't know how to have the system sort the rows whenever the user makes changes to the cell of the "Status" column.
2. I was able to sort the data with the following script by "Date" and "Status," however the rows with the "Finished" status are in between the other statuses. What I want to do is, if there are rows with the "Status" as "Finished" then I want them to be below any other statuses. And within those rows with the "Finished" status, they should be sorted by the "Date" column.

```html
// Global veriables
var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Status");
var dateColumn = 1;
var statusColumn = 7;
var lastRow = app.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = app.getLastColumn();

function dynamicDataSorting() {
  var sortingRange = app.getRange(16, 1, lastRow - 1, lastColumn)
  sortingRange.sort([{column: dateColumn, ascending: false}, {column: statusColumn, ascending: false}]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close to the final solution. This is how I would approach it:

1. Create an auxiliary column (`statusAux`) with this formula: `=if(C2="finished",0,1)` where column `C` is your `statusColumn`. You can hide it with [hideColumn(colmun)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#hidecolumncolumn), [hideColumns(columnIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#hidecolumnscolumnindex) or from the web.
2. Use the following function to sort your data:

```
function onEdit(e)  {
  range.sort([{column: statusAux, ascending: false}, {column: dateColumn, ascending: true}]);
}
```

You can define your `range` inside or outside of the function, it has the same effect.

To understand how triggers work check out [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) and [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

Comment: Hey fullfine! It worked!!!!!!! Thank you so much!!!!!!

Comment: Glad to help! For documentation purposes if you can, please accept the answer (✓) that's been helpful to you - it helps other people that have the same issue in the future find the solution too :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try Arrayformula:

You can create a separate sheet and apply below formula:

```
=Arrayformula(SUBSTITUTE(query(Arrayformula(SUBSTITUTE(A2:E8,"Finished","ZzFinished")),"Select * Order by Col5,Col1 asc"),"ZzFinished","Finished"))
```

Change the data `Range` and `'Col'` number per your need!